# Printing Area Within Webpage

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to print to a primera lx900 label printer which is a 3"x5" label from my website. I have the label printing perfectly to one label, defining the length (255px) and width (455px) as landscape but no matter what I do it prints 3 blank labels printing the empty space till the end of the page. In order to try and troubleshoot I have narrowed my page down to the following code and it's still printing 3 blank labels. I have tried every variation of size, overflow, and @media print with no luck! Please help!

```
css page is
@media print {
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
max-height: 255px !important;
max-width: 455 !important;
}

@page {
margin: 0 !important;
max-width: 455px;
max-height: 255px;
overflow: hidden !important;
}

.templateholder { width: 455px;height: 255px; overflow:hidden !important; }
```

html page is

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/printlabel.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="templateholder" style="margin:0">
test
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I made a quick pdf using fpdf with the correct size to see if that would print correctly. It does the same thing, printing 3 blank labels after the first correct label. The code I used for fpdf below. Does this give any indication as to what's happening?

```
require('fpdf/PDF_MySQL_Table.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('L','in',array(5,3));

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->SetFillColor(135,206,250);
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'Test',0,1,'L');

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: The `overflow:hidden;` is hiding the other labels.

Comment: That's what I was hoping for but it doesn't seem to function that way. I would think - according to the code - that it would hide the other 3 labels but they're still printing.

Comment: Hmmmm.  I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: The computer is windows vista. Could that be causing issues?

Comment: No, mine is too.  But I also checked on the latest mac.

Comment: It won't be fun but do you think creating a pdf to print would do the trick?

Comment: Yes, it would work, but I'm still trying to figure this out . . .

Comment: There was a second custom page size setting for the label printer! Many thanks for your help but it's working fine now

Comment: Wonderful!  It WAS working after all :) GOD IS GOOD . . .